# How do I concatenate values in a SQLlite loop, and return a single string after the loop is done?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

This is a node module. When I run this code the r variable is empty.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db');
  
exports.getNav = function () {
    var r = "";
    db.each(`SELECT * FROM sites`, (err, row) => {
        r=r+ `<a  href="${row.url}">${row.icon}${row.name}</a>`;    
    });
    return `<nav class="nav-left">${r}</nav>`;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to take the database loop outside of the exports function:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db');
  
var r = "";
db.each('SELECT * FROM sites', function (err, row) {
    r=r+ `<a  href="${row.url}">${row.name}</a>`;   
})
db.close()

exports.getNav = function () {
    return `<nav class="nav-left">${r}</nav>`;
};
```